# Problem in client side of Signal R in Internet Explorer and javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, websocket, signalr

I have a POS device which I send price via Signal R and Java Script code, and everything works fine, POS device (Pax S800) turns on and shows price.

**Sending price code**

```
        var serverMessage = '';
        $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";
        var console = $.connection.SSP1126HUB;
        var ip = '';
        console.client.GetSystemResponse = function (message) {
            serverMessage = '';
            serverMessage = message;
        }
        $.connection.hub.start().done(
        function initialize() {
            console.server.Initial(1, ip, 'COM4', 1, 0, '0');
            var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; //1 second
            setTimeout(function () {
                //your code to be executed after 1 second
                if (serverMessage == '0') {
                    console.server.SendAmount1Step(TotalAmount, Amountiban, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ');
                }
                else
                    alert("error");
            }, delayInMilliseconds);

        });
```

For notice, I added jQuery and Signal R codes as scripts to my page.

**Scripts**

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Then when I swipe my card (Successfully paying or resigning from paying) transaction's information won't be sanded from POS device.
Here is the code that never is being called:

**Receiving transaction's information *(not working in IE but working in Google Chrome )***

```
          console.client.GetTransactionResponse = function (TerminalId, ResponseCode, SerialId, RRN, ResponseDescription, TxnDate, CardNumberMask)
          {

               alert("received");

          }
```

So, you may think that scripts are not working fine, but in Google Chrome transaction's information is being received and because my application uses Silverlight, I cannot use Google Chrome.

**My own solutions which didn't work**

- Changing Emulation in developer tools of IE and set different document modes
- Set Low Security in IE
- Disable protected mode
- Disable enhanced protected mode
- I kept developer tools open

I think there's something wrong in web socket connection (client part) so client to server connection is working but server to client (IE as client) is not working. But I don't know how I can solve this problem.

Would be appreciated for giving me possible solutions. Thank you.